# Writing Bits into Binary File in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, binary, bit-manipulation, binaryfiles

I need to create a file that include binary input but when i do this it take as byte not bit

for example if i want to add binary represent of "apple" 
it writes to file 0110000101110000011100000110110001100101 it contains 40 bits 
however when i look at the file it show 40bytes because it takes every bit as char and so it save as byte-wise.
How can i prevent this and save all information bit-wise in VB.net ?

```
Dim fs As New FileStream("\binfile.bin", FileMode.Append)
    Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(fs)
    Dim TempStr As String

    For t As Integer = 0 To Nameoftable.Length - 1
        Dim bin As String = _
            LongToBinary(Asc(Nameoftable.Substring(t, 1))) 'BIT CONVERTER FUNCTION
        TempStr &= bin.Substring(bin.Length - 8)
    Next t

        bw.Write(TempStr)

    bw.Close()
```

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Well, don't use LongToBinary().  It isn't clear why you do.  If you want bytes then StreamWriter will work just fine.

Comment: I use LongToBinary function because, I need to save data as binary because in some part of record I use hashing and bit-wise part needed.. for example i need first bit status of data and after rest of data in this kind of situation i need bitwise record.. The real issue evenif i change all string, integers into binary format, it written as char into .bin file.. how can i prevent this ?

Comment: Moreover i just try streamwriter, this is almost same as binarywriter for mycase.. I need  to write bit-wise.. for example if i add 5 bits into bin file, it must grow 5 bits not 5 bytes..

Answer (score 1):

You must use BINARY reader/writer object and also specify the field-type of the data being sent to the write-stream and the same goes for data being read in the reader from the stream.

```
Dim filename As String = "c:\temp\binfile.bin"
Dim writer As BinaryWriter
Dim reader As BinaryReader
Dim tmpStringData As String
Dim tmpByteData As Byte
Dim tmpCharData As Char
Dim tempIntData as Integer
Dim tempBoolData as Boolean
'
writer = New BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Append))
Using writer
  writer.Write("apple")
  'writer.Write(YourByteDataHere)   'byte
  'writer.Write(YourCharHere)   'char
  'writer.Write(1.31459)        'single
  'writer.Write(100)        'integer
  'writer.Write(False)        'boolean
End Using
writer.Close()
'
If (File.Exists(filename)) Then
  reader = New BinaryReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
  Using reader
    tmpStringData = reader.ReadString()
    'tempByteData = reader.ReadByte()
    'tempCharData = reader.ReadChar()
    'tempSingleData = reader.ReadSingle()
    'tempIntData = reader.ReadInt32()
    'tempBoolData = reader.ReadBoolean()
  End Using
  reader.Close()
End If
```

I used ReadString() method to write the string "apple"
You could use the chr code for a character or byte if you wish, in which case you must use ReadByte() or ReadChar() or ReadInt() depending on how you sent it to the stream (as a byte, char or integer)

So the file size is 6 bytes 1 for its own internal use by the file stream handler and 5 for your 'apple'

And if you saved it as char or byte I would think its 5 bytes used and 1k long
And if you saved it as integer I would think its 10 bytes used and 1k long

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx